# How to properly loop with Numpy array of tuples?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a Numpy 2D matrix of zeros, and a Numpy list of coordinates.
What I would like to do, is modify the matrix thanks to the list of coordinates by passing it in a function.

Here is what I tried :

```
import numpy as np

def update(coords):
    return np_arr[coords[0]][coords[1]]+1

size = 3
np_arr = np.zeros((size,size))
dt = np.dtype('int', 'int')
np_indices = np.array([(x,y) for y in range(size) for x in range(size)], dtype=dt)
np_arr = update(np_indices)
print(np_arr)
```

I expected the output to be a `size*size` matrix:

```
[[1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1.]]
```

But instead I get:

```
[[1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1.]]
```

Why does the shape of the matrix is not the same?

I know that I could simply use:

```
np_arr = np.array([[update(x,y) for y in range(size)] for x in range(size)])
```

However, I would like to avoid using np.array every time.

Comment: what exactly are your trying to do? Your current code takes `np_arr`, indexes it with only the first coordinate in `coords` on the first axis and thus returns a (2, n) array. You must clearly explain the logic. What should be the output for `np_arr = np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)` as input?

Comment: A meshgrid would be a much cleaner solution to this instead of a matrix of tuples.

Comment: You have `np_indices[0] -> [0,0]`.
`np_arr[[0,0]]` means select row 0 and row 0. Which is `[[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]` and then you apply +1 on this (2,3) array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
In [484]: size = 3
     ...: np_arr = np.zeros((size,size))
     ...: dt = np.dtype('int', 'int')
     ...: np_indices = np.array([(x,y) for y in range(size) for x in range(size)], dtype=dt)

In [485]: np_arr
Out[485]: 
array([[0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0.]])
```

Despite using the compound `dt`, the `np_indices` array is a 2d `int` dtype array.  Were you hoping to get an array of tuples?

```
In [486]: np_indices
Out[486]: 
array([[0, 0],
       [1, 0],
       [2, 0],
       [0, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [2, 1],
       [0, 2],
       [1, 2],
       [2, 2]])
```

Anyways, the way to index `np_arr` is to use the 2 columns, as in:

```
In [487]: np_arr[np_indices[:,0],np_indices[:,1]]
Out[487]: array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.])

In [488]: np_arr[np_indices[:,0],np_indices[:,1]]+=1

In [489]: np_arr
Out[489]: 
array([[1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1.]])
```

You can't use `np_arr[np_indices[:,0]][np_indices[:,1]`.  That applies the 2 indexing operations sequentially.  It works for scalar indices, `np_arr[2,3], np_arr[2][3]`, but not when using arrays.  And `np_indices[0]` is the first row, not column.

```
In [490]: size = 3
     ...: np_arr = np.zeros((size,size))
     ...: dt = np.dtype([('x','int'), ('y','int')])
     ...: np_indices = np.array([(x,y) for y in range(size) for x in range(size)], dtype=dt)

In [491]: np_indices
Out[491]: 
array([(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1), (2, 1), (0, 2), (1, 2),
       (2, 2)], dtype=[('x', '<i4'), ('y', '<i4')])
```

With a different `dt`, we get a `1d structured array`:

```
In [492]: np_indices['x']
Out[492]: array([0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2])
```

We still need to use the 2 array indexing:

```
In [493]: np_arr[np_indices['x'],np_indices['y']]
Out[493]: array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.])
```

The structured array could be used in loop:

```
In [495]: [np_arr[x,y] for x,y in np_indices]
Out[495]: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```

but generally we avoid that.